# Как передать имя таблицы в функцию как параметр?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Я использую Entity Framework. Есть некая функция, в которой происходит заполнение `dataGridView` данными из таблицы.

```
private void data()
{
    using (Context context = new Context())
    {
        var items = from Items in context.Table1
                    select Items;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = items.ToList();
    }
}
```

Но я хочу сделать универсальную функцию, чтобы имя таблицы передавалось через параметр. Подскажите, как нужно модифицировать функцию, чтобы это стало возможным?

Что-то типа этого:

```
void Test()
{
    data(tbl1);
    data(tbl2);
}

private void data(SomeType tableName)
{
    using (Context context = new Context())
    {
        var items = from Items in tableName
                    select Items;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = items.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если тип сущностей в таблицах одинаковый, то можно попробовать спустить функцию для выбора таблицы параметром:

```
void Test()
{
    data(c => c.tbl1);
    data(c => c.tbl2);
}

private void data(Func<Context, IQueryable<SomeType>> tableSelector)
{
    using (Context context = new Context())
    {
        var items = from Items in tableSelector(context)
                    select Items;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = items.ToList();
    }
}
```

Если разный - добавьте генерик-параметр

```
private void data<T>(Func<Context, IQueryable<T>> tableSelector)
{
    using (Context context = new Context())
    {
        var items = from Items in tableSelector(context)
                    select Items;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = items.ToList();
    }
}
```

<sub>в живую не проверял, возможны опечатки</sub>

Если нужно передавать имя таблицы именно как строку - придётся использовать reflection. Постарайтесь избегать этого :)

Comment: Вроде работает. Но почему-то постоянно запускается Garbage Collector.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin ну вы выбирате данные и создаете пачку объектов При создании объектов вы превышает лимит 0-го поколения, что запускает gc. Это полностью нормальный процесс, а не что-то что надо чинить.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin я бы на месте разработчиков студии вообще это окно убрал по умолчанию - оно приводит начинающих к неправильным выводам - что gc - это индикатор проблемы, например. Хотя на самом деле это полностью рядовое и заурядное событие :)

Comment: Срабатывание GC происходит несколько раз в секунду и длится постоянно. При этом dataGridView помаргивает. Это нормально?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin нет, не нормально. вы скорее всего вызываете этот код в цикле. или по таймеру. поэтому он постояно выбирает данные и постоянно обновляет грид. но в самом коде проблемы нет.

Comment: Нет ни цикла, ни таймера. Это простейший тестовый пример. Из события `dataGridView1_Paint` вызывается функция `private void data<T>(Func<Context, IQueryable<T>> tableSelector)`

Comment: @MikhailDanshin и эта функция меняет датасорс. что вызывает перерисовку грида. при перерисовке вызывается событие Paint, в котором вы вызываете функцию ... и так бесконечно. уберите вызов из paint. поставьте заполнение грида данными в OnLoad, или привяжите его на нажатие какой-нибудь кнопки.

Comment: OnLoad не нахожу такого. А по кнопке - это неудобно. :(

Comment: @MikhailDanshin поищите OnLoad формы, а не самого грида

Comment: Все работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться `SqlQuery`:

```
var sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", tablename);
var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<OBJECT>(sql);
```

Как правило Entity == таблица, по этому можно сделать так:

```
IQueryable<SomeEntity> query = context.Set<SomeEntity>();
```

Или так:

```
PropertyInfo entityProperty = efcontext.GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t.Name == e).Single();
    var baseQuery = (IQueryable<IMyEntity>)entity.GetValue(efContext, null);
    var result = baseQuery.Where(t => ...);
```

Или так:

```
var tblNoteProperties = contextEntities
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p =>
                p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
            .Select(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0])
            .Where(t => t.Name == "tblName")
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: А `SomeEntity` - это что?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin тип сущности

Comment: Какой именно сущности? Я только начинаю знакомиться с EF. Не могли бы Вы привести законченный пример функции и ее вызова?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin той, с которой вы собираетесь работать.